# PayPal IPN not able to pass website sign in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, devise, paypal-ipn

I am working on a ruby on rails project and need to use Paypal to allow a user to buy some coins usable on the website. To make the process as simple as possible I am just using a buy now button supplied by Paypal. The button is set up to notify a URL that will add the coins to a current user when accessed.

The website is set up so that if you are not logged in you can not access any page on the site. Here in lies the problem. I assumed that devise would be able to access the URL Paypal is trying to use by using the account last logged in. This dose not seem to be the case as tailing the heroku logs informs me that Paypal tries to go to the correct URL but is then forwarded to the sign in screen and the coins are not added.

In short my question is how can I allow the Paypal IPN to bypass the sign in screen while keeping the info for the last user that was signed in (So that I can access the correct current user in the code)

Hopefully I have provided enough info. If not I can post any requested code, or logs. Thanks for any assistance.

**Update**
Useing the code below the program no longer forwards to paypal. Unfortunately current user is now null. So now the question becomes how can I retain the current use information?

**Controller the url points to**

```
class PaymentNotificationsController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!, :except => [:create]
# POST /payment_notifications
# POST /payment_notifications.json

def create
puts "made it here"
#PaymentNotification.create!(:params => params)
current_user.coins += 100
current_user.save!
render :nothing => true
end

end
```

**Aplication Controller**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
before_action :authenticate_user!
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
end
```

Comment: In the case that you may add methods that need authentication.. try :authenticate_user!, :except => [:create]

Answer (score 0):

Not being super familiar with how PayPal works I would *guess* using :require_no_authentication for the endpoint paypal is accessing and restricting access by using a token might do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Im testing it now and will let you know.

Comment: Same issue is occurring. It still appears forwarding the request to the /users/sign_in page, making it useless.

Comment: it's shouldn't forward there if you successfully allow it to skip auth for the target endpoint.

Comment: I agree. The target endpoint is the controller that the url points to correct? I'll add the code I tried to my question. Hopefully I'm just making a dumb mistake.

Comment: Maybe try this form for the action that provides the endoint: before_action :authenticate_user!, :except => [:ENDPOINT_METHOD]

Comment: before_action :authenticate_user!, :except => [:create] Worked! Unfortunately now the current user is nil.

Comment: attach the user to the object PayPal is referencing then use as it as necessary?

Comment: That makes sense. Unfortunately I have no Idea how to do that.

Comment: I'm guessing there is a user_id field on the object paypal is looking up referencing the User in question.

Comment: That would be awesome but I don't believe so

Comment: create a belongs_to :user association on the payment model paypal is looking for.

Comment: What? I can't (or don't know how at least) alter or add info that is given back to me in the IPN except when Im making the buy now button on the Paypal site, meaning the info can't be dynamic.